# Getting Average based on distinct row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table users containing the fields userID,age,gender and i have another table
name as click_info containing fields(id,userID,clickID) The enrty in the click_info table are as following

```
id       userID      dubID

1          1           2

2          1           2

3          1           2

4          2           2

5          2           2

6          3           2

7          4           2
```

Now I want the average age of all the users who clicked on dubID 2  and i am using the following query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `dub_clickinfo`.`userID`, `users`.`age` AS `average`, `users`.*
FROM `dub_clickinfo` INNER JOIN `users` ON dub_clickinfo.userId = users.userID 
WHERE (dubID=2)
```

The above query gives the incorrect average it will include the duplicate userID (like it will include userID 1 three times,2 two times) as well.

Please suggest a query

Thanks In Advance !!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the [Code Sample `{}`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VYd26.png) toolbar button—I've done it for you this time.

Comment: You want to return a single value only which is the Average of all Users age which has dubID=2? Is that right?

Comment: What would the desired result look like?

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try ,there is a one to many relation so you need to use left join not inner ,and apply a group function on user's id

```
SELECT dub_clickinfo.userID, users.age AS average, users.* FROM dub_clickinfo 
LEFT JOIN users ON dub_clickinfo.userId = users.userID WHERE (dubID=2)
GROUP BY users.userID
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT avg(age) FROM users WHERE userID in (select distinct userID from dub_clickinfo where dubID ='2')
```

Comment: Yes you are correct but still you are using subquery i don't want to go with subquery because it takes time when number of record is increase..